# Access WCF service behind Azure AD from Net core

Tags: wcf, .net-core, azure-active-directory, .net-6.0

I have a WCF Service (using HttpBasicBinding), it is a part of a WebApp (written with .Net Framework 4.8). WebApp is registered with Azure AD and thing works fine with the login. Now I want to access WCF from other WebApp (written with NET 6 and also register with Azure AD). I generated WCF Client using dotnet-svcutil, but it cannot connect to WCF service, because I don't know what to put in ClientCredentials/token/Bearer or something like this.
Page

Comment: Check this [Accessing Azure AD Authenticated Web App](https://www.advaiya.com/accessing-azure-ad-authenticated-web-app-in-applications/) in applications document may help.

Comment: I solved the problem by using access token like this https://github.com/mikelapierre/LegacyAppService

Answer (score 0):

You can using the Service Reference
find the name of the client class and operation you want to use. `Reference.cs` will contain a class that inherits from `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`, with methods that can be used to call operations on the service.
You can refer to the following article:

 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x 
https://www.thecodebuzz.com/consuming-wcf-web-services-in-net-core-using-global-tool/

Comment: Hi, actually I have the generated client, but the problem is WCF Service is protected by Azure AD and I don't know what to put/ add to client  so it can call the service

Comment: Hope [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1092557/WCF-Security-and-Authentication-in-Azure-WsHttpBin) can help you

Comment: I solved the problem by using access token like this https://github.com/mikelapierre/LegacyAppService